# Do we still need stored procedures when using compiled queries?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, compiled-query

When using compiled queries in entity framework (or linq-to-sql) in combination with SQL Server, is there actually still any performance benefit in using stored procedures?

Compiled queries will be cached as parameterized queries, so performance should be near equal to stored procedures. Is there any situation where stored procedures would perform significantly better?

-- EDIT --

In response to Yakimych's answer below, I didn't mean to imply that compiled queries are the same as stored procedures. I am trying to figure out if sprocs are still necessary if you have done all possible optimizations on the application side (in this case compiled queries). So I guess I'm looking for reasons why a stored procedure would be better than the **combination** of application-side optimizations and parameterized queries (which is what compiled queries effectively are).

One of the reasons I'm asking this, is because there are many people who seem to think that stored proedures are no longer necessary for different reasons (i.e. [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2003/11/18/38178.aspx)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Is there any situation where stored procedures would perform significantly better?"

Given a comparable piece of parametrized SQL generated in either EF or a stored proc, they will perform equally.

However, a DBA always has the opportunity to further optimise a query based on their experience with the DB schema and its usage patterns.  A stored procedure allows them to do this easily in isolation of the applications using it, whereas an ORM doesn't.

We have an extremely complicated SQL Server DB that has many external systems replicating data in and out via triggers.  The issue for us with EF is that the responsibility for the SQL that gets fired at the DB will become the application developers responsibility when using any ORM rather than the DBAs.

Comment: +1 though unfortunately every job I've worked at that has required using stored procedures made creating/updating them the job of the developers anyways..

Answer (score 9):

First of all, compiling EF queries has nothing to do with performance benefits that can be achieved by using stored procedures.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx - the following operations occur when a query executes against a conceptual model:

> - Loading metadata
> - Opening the database connection
> - Generating views
> - **Preparing the query**
> - Executing the query
> - Loading and validating types
> - Tracking
> - Materializing the objects

And the explanation regarding `Preparing the query`:

> Includes the costs to compose the query command, generate a command tree based on model and mapping metadata, and define the shape of the returned data. Because Entity SQL query commands are cached, later executions of the same query take even less time. You can also use compiled LINQ queries to reduce this cost in later executions.

So, if you compile the query and re-use it later, what happens is that you save time on this operation in your application during every subsequent query execution. What you don't do, however, is you don't influence the generated SQL code that is executed against the database. **The performance benefits you get when compiling queries are at the application level.**

On the other hand, you would typically use stored procedures in case you aren't satisfied with the generated SQL code and would like to optimize performance at the database level.

**EDIT** in response to your comment and edit.

It seems to me that you are under the impression that compiling an EF query would somehow change the generated SQL code that will be run against the database (you mention that compiled queries result in parametrized SQL queries?). That is not the case. No matter whether you run the query directly or use `compiledQuery.Invoke`, *the same SQL code will be run against the DB*. Furthermore, you don't have full control over it, you rather rely on the ORM to generate it in the best possible way. In some cases it is not optimal, and this is where SP's come in.

So to sum up:

- Compiling queries is purely an
  application-side optimization. It
  saves the time to compile a query
  that gets re-used in the code.
- Stored procedures can be used to tweak your SQL code and get it to match your goal as closely as possible, thus providing a possibility to get the best performance at the database level.

In no way is one technique a substitute for the other.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that compiled queries are the same as stored procedures (that's why I mentioned they are cached as parameterized queries). What I meant was, if your ORM produces parameterized queries (EF or any other for that matter), is there still any reason to use stored procedures. I'm sorry if this was not entirely clear, I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your comment and edit. (Hope I understand you correctly)

Comment: No I am not under the impression that compiling an EF query changes generated SQL code at all. I know that a compiled query has nothing to do with a stored procedure. The point is that a query produced by EF (whether it is compiled or not) will be optimized and cached in sql server just like a stored procedure. I'm looking for a comparison between two query request styles if you like: stored procesures on the one hand, and EF generated (compiled) queries on the other hand.

Comment: If you do realize that both a compiled and non-compiled query will be `'optimized and cached in sql server just like a stored procedure'`, why does the question relate to *compiled* queries? Regarding the actual discussion - in one case EF will create and run a parametrized query, in the other, an SP will be called. If the SQL code in both cases is the same, there won't be any significant performance difference, and in this case I agree with you - there is no point in using an SP.

Comment: I think he is confusing "compiled queries" with "parameterized queries"

Answer (score 3):

A few canned answers from well known experts: Paul Nielsen [Why use Stored Procedures?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2009/05/09/why-use-stored-procedures.aspx)

Adam Machanic: [No, stored procedures are NOT bad](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/no-stored-procedures-are-not-bad.aspx)